# How do I return multiple rows one at a time from a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to return a set that is created dynamically inside a stored procedure (for the sake of simplicity, let's say the set is a list of even numbers that are calculated inside a loop).

Some databases I've worked with had a `SUSPEND` operation that added the current values of the `OUT` parameters to the result set of the procedure, like so:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE EvenNumbers(
    IN n INT, OUT NUM INT )
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE i < n DO
        SET NUM = i;
        SUSPEND; /* adds a row with a value 'i' for column NUM to the result set */
        SET i = i+2;
    END WHILE;
END$

DELIMITER ;
```

`SUSPEND` is a keyword in MySQL but I assume it doesn't do the same thing because this doesn't work (`Error: Unexpected 'SUSPEND'`).

So, how do I return a set of rows one by one from a stored procedure in MySQL?

Comment: There is no such thing as "one at a time". A stored procedure runs to completion and you get the results. If you want to stream those results to your client, that's on you.

Comment: @tadman I'm fine with storing the results somewhere and returning them to the client at the end of the procedure but I don't know how to do that in MySQL (except maybe with a temporary table but that sound like an overkill).

Answer (score 2):

Alex,
you can create a temporary table inside the stored procedure (which is perfectly ok), store the result of the calculation in it and return the content of the temp table once you are done with the calculations. So, instead of the OUT parameters, use normal result set returned by the procedure.

Comment: I did end up doing that, although it seems a little fragile (not dropping the temporary table would result in an error in a subsequent call), plus it pollutes the tables namespace (I have to make sure the same table name isn't used anywhere in the same database). I would prefer a local TABLE variable, if MySQL has that.

Comment: If you use "create temporary table", there is no pollution of the tables namespace. When you use temporary table, it is unique inside the connection and lives until the connection is closed or until you drop it. To make things safe, you can do "drop temporary table my_tmp if exists" before creating the temp table, or just do "drop temporary table my_tmp" at the end of the procedure.

Comment: If I use `create temporary table` there is no pollution of the tables namespace *outside the context of the current connection*. I still have to make sure the name I use for my temporary table isn't used anywhere else. What's more, if someone decides to use the same name for another table later, an error will show up only when the stored procedure is executed, so everyone else HAS to be aware of that decision. Overall the temporary table solution is an abstraction leak from the procedure - the procedure is no longer self-contained.

Comment: There is only one thread inside one connection, so there can be only one instance using the temporary table at one time. A good practice is to use "drop temporary table my_tmp if exists" befote you create the temp table and then "drop temporary table my_tmp" at the end of the procedure / when you no longer need it. Dropping it will make sure you do not have conflict within same connection. The only use case you need to take care of, is that if a stored procedure calls another stored procedure that these two do not use same temp table in a way that they confilct (you can use this to pass data)

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want a even number generator? 
This is pure MySQL without making use of stored procedure.

First you need to generate a lot off numbers with the query below.
This query generates 1 to 10000 records.

**Query**

```
  SELECT 
    @row := @row + 1 AS ROW
  FROM  
  (
     SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) row2
  CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) row3
    CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) row4  

  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0
  ) init_user_param
```

The main query.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 *
FROM (

  SELECT 
    @row := @row + 1 AS ROW
  FROM  
  (
     SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) row2
  CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) row3
    CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
  ) row4  

  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0
  ) init_user_param

) 
 ROWS
WHERE
  ROWS.ROW BETWEEN 1 AND 10
 AND
  ROWS.ROW MOD 2 = 0
```

**Result**

```
   row  
--------
       2
       4
       6
       8
      10
```

Comment: Thank you but the even numbers were just an example. I'm looking for a general solution where each row to be returned is determined by a complex calculation inside a loop.